# How to download ZIP file from reactjs using post api?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to download zip file from reactjs using POST API. 
The request is coming from nodejs in binary form

Comment: Welcome to SO ;) Please read this article on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This would include a proper description of what you are trying to achieve, your code (or the relevant snippets) as well as your efforts showing what you have tried so far and possible error messages. It is also advisable to provide a full [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)..

Answer (score 1):

you can use jszip link  https://github.com/Stuk/jszip like

```
import zipTargetFiles from '/path'

zipTargetFiles( data ).then(file => {
 //operations
})
```

if you use fetch like this.

```
fetch('URL', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    //Body
  })
}).then((response)=>{
//here is youu want zip data 
var zip = new JSZip();
var zipData = response.data // 
// Add an top-level, arbitrary text file with contents
zip.file("response.txt", zipData);

// Generate the zip file asynchronously
zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"})
.then(function(content) {
    // Force down of the Zip file
    saveAs(content, "zipFile.zip");
});

}).catch((error)=>{
console.log(error)
})
```

Comment: The api is post. SO how can i download it

Answer (score 1):

You can use JsZip on Client Side. Then, do a request with axios. Like this:

```
request = (currentUrl: string): Promise<void> => axios({
    url: currentUrl,
    method: 'GET',
    responseType: 'blob',
}).then((response) => {
    const url: string = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
});
```

Comment: The api is post. SO how can i download it?

Comment: I missed that completely.But why are you using a POST Api when actually you are getting data from server ?I do not think that is right way to call an api

Comment: But the situation is.. in the post body we are providing files paths in the array form and that file will get ziped.