# How can I download a zipped folder from a post API in REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a task to implement a download for files in excel format and images contained in a folder as a zip file. The API is a post but I use the JSzip library and I've not being able to get a proper implementation.

```
import { saveAs } from "file-saver";
import JSZip from "jszip";

function Download({ apiToken }) {
  const [category, setCategory] = useState([]);
  
 
  //click to download function
  const handleClick = () => {
    setButtonText("Downloading...");
    

    const params = JSON.stringify({
      subcategoryiid: category,
    });

    Axios({
      url: `${baseUrl}/cards/details`,
      method: "POST",
      responseType: "blob",
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${apiToken}`,
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: params,
    })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);

        let zip = new JSZip();
        let zipData = res.data;
        zip.folder("project.zip", zipData);

        zip.generateAsync({ type: "blob" }).then((content) => {
          // Force down of the Zip file
          saveAs(content, "project.zip");
        });

      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        setButtonText("Download");
        
      });
  };

  

  return (
    <div>
 
        <TextField
          className="box"
          placeholder="enter facility code"
          required
          value={category}
          onChange={(e) => setCatergory(e.target.value)}
        />
         
        
       
        <Button
          type="button"
          color="success"
          variant="contained"
          onClick={handleClick}
        >
          {buttonText}
        </Button>
      </Paper>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Download;
```

I want to be able to read the file and download the folder(containing different files and images) as zip for the user to extract. The zip comes in empty whereas in the browser console it contains some files. I would appreciate any help please

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55653061/how-to-download-zip-file-from-reactjs-using-post-api you can have a look at this

Answer (score 0):

This how I solve this case.

My Service

```
async download(appName: string): Promise<any> {

        return fetch(`${this.URL}/download/${appName}`)
            .then(transfer => transfer.blob())
            .then(bytes => {
                let elm = document.createElement('a');
                elm.href = URL.createObjectURL(bytes);
                elm.setAttribute('download', `${appName}.zip`);
                elm.click()
                return true;
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            })
    }
```

How I call it

```
const onDownload = async () => {
        setLoading(true);
        const resp = await generateService.download(app.projectName);
        if (resp) {
            setLoading(false);
        }
    }
```